# Dynamic range and offset in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am looking for some help constructing a dynamic range formula that can skip rows.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(H111;5;0;COUNTA(H111:H116) + 1;1))
```

My idea was to start at `H111` and move down 5 rows, use `COUNTA` to count all non-blank rows and add 1 to adjust for one blank title/colored row in between.

What I want to do is, is to be able to `SUM` all the accumulated amortizations for every asset in the total amortization cost field and to be able to add new items which the formula dynamically responds to.

[image: screenshot of the worksheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function) for this.

SUMIF() looks in a range that you specify for a criteria that you also specify, and sums the corresponding values in another column.  In your case, put this formula in H105:

`=SUMIF(A:A,A111,H:H)`

This looks in all of column A for the value in A11 (Accumulated amortization) and sums the corresponding values in column H.  The sum will include any values you add in the future.

You could also specify smaller ranges, i.e. A111:A150 and H111:H150, where the end of the range is farther down than any new values you might add.

Hope this helps, and best of luck.